# Do I need a Russian visa if i have a layover in Irkutsk or Ulan Ude?

Tags: layovers

Do I need a Russian visa if i have a layover in Irkutsk or Ulan Ude?
I come from Europe, so I usually need a visa for Russia.

Comment: Are you going to leave the airport? Do you have separate tickets?

Comment: Same ticket from s7, i dont leave the airport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timatic warns that there are no transit facilities at Irkutsk and several other airports. To transit through them, you need to have a visa to enter Russia.

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They
>   must stay in the international transit area of the airport and
>   have documents required for the next destination.
>
> - TWOV does not apply to passengers arriving from Belarus.
> - TWOV does not apply to passengers departing to Belarus.
> - TWOV does not apply to passengers arriving from Sevastopol   (UKS) or Simferopol (SIP).
> - TWOV does not apply to passengers departing to Sevastopol
>     (UKS) or Simferopol (SIP).
> - TWOV does not apply at Irkutsk (IKT), Kaliningrad (KGD),
>     Khabarovsk (KHV), Krasnodar (KRR), Mineralnye Vody (MRV),
>     Rostov-on-Don (ROV), Sochi (AER) and Yuzhno Sakhalinsk
>     (UUS).
>
> Warning:
>
> - There are no transit facilities at Irkutsk (IKT),
>     Kaliningrad (KGD), Khabarovsk (KHV), Krasnodar (KRR),
>     Mineralnye Vody (MRV), Rostov-on-Don (ROV), Sochi (AER) and
>     Yuzhno Sakhalinsk (UUS), passengers must comply with all
>     entry regulations for Russian Fed.

Comment: Ulan Ude airport is really small compare with Irkutsk so i think same problem here... so i need to change flight. thanks for the informations.. i really want a Russian visa more cheaper or 30 days free for see that country again!

Comment: Baikal airport is building a new international terminal but it will not be ready until 2024!

Comment: Oh Really?? That is a great news! Thanks so much!!